How can I generate a Dynamic QR Code in excel
How can I generate a dynamic QR Code in excel that I can edit whenever I make changes to any cell. The QR code must contain information from 3 or 4 cells. Thanks for your potential help.
I tried generating one using QR4Office but it's not putting it into excel as it generates an image and I can't change it.

If the web address is in cell A1 this should work:  =IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" & A1).  I haven't added as an answer as it's blocked from where I am so can't fully check it.

Tested this one and it works:  =IMAGE("https://quickchart.io/qr?text=" & A1)

Thank you. I have tried and it works. Now the problem is adding more cells to that and making sure there is line breaks. Can you kindly assist if you can

Could you edit your question (edit button is just below the tags at the bottom of your question) and add what you mean by more cells and line breaks?  Maybe an image would help?  Normally I'd suggest a mark-down table that can be copied and pasted, but think an image might be more help here.  I take it the 3 or 4 cells makes up a web address of some sort
